# Calling from extended class

Tags: java, function, methods, enums, abstract

For my project I have to create an abstract class Character and then create a class Player that extends Character. Because class, Character, is abstract I cannot call it to the main and instead I have to call the class Player to the main. My attempt to call the class is in the switch case in AdventureGameV3 which is the main function. Any ideas on how to call it. I have also attached the Weapon class, but it shouldn't be to essential to my question.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public abstract class Character {

final int ROGUE_INIT_HP = 55;
final int ROGUE_INIT_STRENGTH = 8;
final int PALADIN_INIT_HP = 35;
final int PALADIN_INIT_STRENGTH = 14;
final int CHAN_INIT_HP = 45;
final int CHAN_INIT_STRENGTH = 10;

private String name;
private int hitPoints;
private int strength;
private int weapon;



public enum Type{ROGUE, PALADIN, JACKIE_CHAN, GOBLIN, SKELETON, WIZARD}

Type cType;

//holds data for each character
public Character(Type cType) {
    this.cType = cType;
    switch(cType){
        case ROGUE:
            this.name="ROGUE";
            this.hitPoints=ROGUE_INIT_HP;
            this.strength=ROGUE_INIT_STRENGTH;
            Weapon weapon1 = new Weapon(name,Weapon.SHORT_SWORD_MIN,Weapon.SHORT_SWORD_MAX);
            this.weapon = weapon1.getDamage();
            break;
        case PALADIN:
            this.name="PALADIN";
            this.hitPoints=PALADIN_INIT_HP;
            this.strength=PALADIN_INIT_STRENGTH;
            Weapon weapon2 = new Weapon(name,Weapon.LONG_SWORD_MIN,Weapon.LONG_SWORD_MAX);
            this.weapon = weapon2.getDamage();
            break;
        case JACKIE_CHAN:
            this.name="JACKIE CHAN";
            this.hitPoints=CHAN_INIT_HP;
            this.strength=CHAN_INIT_STRENGTH;
            Weapon weapon3 = new    Weapon(name,Weapon.JUMP_KICK_MIN,Weapon.JUMP_KICK_MAX);
            this.weapon = weapon3.getDamage();
            break;

    }
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public int getHitPoints()
{
    return hitPoints;
}
public int getStrength()
{
    return strength;
}
public void setStrength(int strength)
{
    this.strength=strength;
}
public void setWeapon(int weapon)
{
    this.weapon=weapon;
}
public void attack()
{

}
public void increaseHitPoints(int pointIncrease)
{
    hitPoints+=pointIncrease;
}
public void decreaseHitPoints(int pointDecrease)
{
    hitPoints-=pointDecrease;
}
public boolean isDefeated()
{
    if(hitPoints>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

```
public class Player extends Character{
private int coins;
private String[] Potion;

public Player(Type playerType){
    super(playerType);
    coins=0;
    String[] inventory = new String[5];
}

public void increaseStrength(int strengthIncrease){
    super.setStrength(super.getStrength() + strengthIncrease);
}

public int getCoins(){
    return coins;
}
public int increaseCoins(int coins){
    this.coins+=coins;
}   
public int decreaseCoins(int coins){
    this.coins-=coins;
}
```

}

```
  public class AdventureGameV3
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
final int ROGUE_INIT_HP = 55;
final int ROGUE_INIT_STRENGTH = 8;
final int PALADIN_INIT_HP = 35;
final int PALADIN_INIT_STRENGTH = 14;
final int CHAN_INIT_HP = 45;
final int CHAN_INIT_STRENGTH = 10;

final int MINION_INIT_HP = 25;
final int GOBLIN_INIT_STRENGTH = 4;
final int SKELETON_INIT_STRENGTH = 3;

int characterChoice = 0;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("\nAdventure Game - Start!\n");
    System.out.println("Here are the characters:");
    System.out.println("1. Rogue\n2. Paladin\n3. Jackie Chan\n");


     System.out.print("Which character do you choose?: ");
     characterChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
     switch(characterChoice){
     case 1:
        Character player = Type(ROGUE);
        break;


     }
      System.out.printf("\nYou chose: %s\n\n", player1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Player class.

```
System.out.println("\nAdventure Game - Start!\n");
System.out.println("Here are the characters:");
System.out.println("1. Rogue\n2. Paladin\n3. Jackie Chan\n");

Player player;
System.out.print("Which character do you choose?: ");
characterChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
switch(characterChoice){
case 1:
   player = new Player(Type.ROGUE);
   break;


}
System.out.printf("\nYou chose: %s\n\n", player);
```

Comment: GrybośI tried your coding "player=new Player(Type.ROGUE);" and when I compile my main, it says "error: cannot find symbol". Any ideas?

Comment: Is the enum Type visible in AdventureGameV3 class?
public enum Type{ROGUE, PALADIN, JACKIE_CHAN, GOBLIN, SKELETON, WIZARD}

Comment: Accoding to the rubric, the public enum Type{ROGUE...} is in the abstract character class, so it would not be. This is why I am extremely confused on  how I would call this to the main.

Comment: @T. Bui , Sorry, my bad; if Character class is in the same package(which I assume is), try this:
player = new Player(Character.Type.ROGUE);

Comment: I tried that, but it says that it cannot find symbol. But i tried doing, "Player player = new Player(Character.Type.ROGUE");" and that seemed to work. But now in the "System.out.printf("\nYou chose: %s\n\n", player);" it says that it cannot find the variable player. Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you don't declare whole "Player player = new Player(Character.Type.ROGUE")" in switch case, but just "player = new Player(Character.Type.ROGUE")", when "Player player" is before switch case construction.

Am I right? 
Also, overload toString method in Player class, if you want this printed "prettier" way :)

Comment: Could you elaborate I'm still confused? Because when I declare it as just "player = new Player(Character.Type.ROGUE);" in the switch case I get an error. Also, it still doesn't like my printf statement when I use "player" as the variable.

Comment: Ok, let's enlight everything.
First, you need to declare Player player at the beggining, before switch case construction.
Then, in case 1: you assign new Player(Character.Type.ROGUE) to player variable.
Leaving switch construction you want to print player information, but here lies a problem. Variable player may have not been initialized.

Here you have 2 options:
1. Move print to case 1:, before break statment;
2. Make sure that player will be properly initialized, for example make default type before switch, or make default assign in switch by last, 'default' case

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much that makes complete sense! You don't understand how much you just helped me!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a enumeration "Type" to a (abstract) class "Character". This is a type mismatch and results in a compile error.

What you want to do is create a new Player instance.

I advise you to use an integrated development environment (IDE) such as Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans that hint you to compile-time errors and help you find the bugs early on. :)

Comment: In the rubric, it says:
*Character(abstract class)
  -Public enum
    Name: Type
    Values:ROGUE,PALADIN....
Would I be able to put this public enum in the player class?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html on how to use enums. I think it will make the usage and instanciation of an enum type clearer.

Comment: I've read this article before and I am still very unclear on how to implement an enum with a constructor(required in Character class). Any hints?